# How can I use nltk.sents() on a .txt file?

Tags: python, nltk, txt

I need to read a single file into an nltk corpus, but when I read the file, it looks like gibberish. Here is my code:

```
corpus_root = 'C:/Users/chaythorn/PycharmProjects/assign2/assign2'
tiny_corp = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*txt')   
test = tiny_corp.sents()
print(test)
```

But my output looks like this -- (this is just a sample... you get the picture)

```
 [['{"', 'the', 'golden', '":', '0', '.', '043', ',', '"', 'golden', 'bird', '":', '0', '.', '391', ',', '"', 'bird', 'a', '":', '0', '.', '038', ',', '"', 'a', 'certain', '":', '0', '.', '007', ',', '"', 'certain', 'king', '":', '1', '.', '0', ',', '"', 'king', 'had', '":', '0', '.', '071', ',', '"', 'had', 'a', '":', '0',   .
```

I can tell that this is the correct file, but obviously something is going wrong when it reads it. The file is utf8 encoded.
My main goal is to be able to use the nltk.sents() function on the file. Reading advice online, it seems like I have to get the files into a corpus first. If there is a different way to use .sents on a txt file, I am open to it.
Thank you!

Comment: doesn't seem like giberish to me, it looks like badly parsed `json` file

Comment: You are right. I did in fact have the wrong file.